# jQuery How i do solve a Jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, html

i put 2 jquery plugin together inside a webpage. Conflict happen between the 2 jquery. When i take out 1 of the plugin code. It work. But when i put in 2 together. just 1 of jquery wil working well.

Can anyone help me solve tis?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<!--slide show-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slideshow.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/backgroundslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slideshow.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEvent('domready',function(){
            var obj = {
                wait: 2000, 
                effect: 'fade',
                duration: 1000, 
                loop: true, 
                thumbnails: true,
                backgroundSlider: true,
                onClick: function(i){}
            }
            show = new SlideShow('slideshowContainer','slideshowThumbnail',obj);
            show.play();
        });
</script>

<!--Contact Slide-->
<link type="text/css" href="css/reset_contact.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be using MooTools and jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script>
...
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Both libraries I believe use the `$` shorthand.  You will need to setup one or the other to not-use `$` to avoid cross pollination of your code.
'
Check out [this article](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) on jQuery and other libraries.  Basically you call `noConflict()` like so:

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
```

and then in all your jQuery code, use `jQuery` in place of `$`:

```
$('foo').bar();
```

becomes

```
jQuery('foo').bar();
```